# How to speed up a cross search on different MySql Servers?

Tags: mysql, performance, select, recordset

I have the following problem. A Classic ASP application needs to access 2 different DB (tables) on two different mysql servers (different remote locations, accessed via IP over the net). The goal is to select all records matching a couple of conditions from the first DB table on the first server (making a recordset), and then, among these records, just select those whose IdCode match with the IdCode of (at least) one record from the DB table on the second server, together with a third condition to match in this second table.
I have a simple (stupid) way to do this which is:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Serv1_Table1 WHERE condition1 AND condition2;"
SET rs = conn1.Execute(strSQL)
DO WHILE NOT rs.EOF
  strSQL = "SELECT IdCode FROM Serv2_Table2 WHERE IdCode=" & rs("IdCode") & " AND condition3 LIMIT 1;"
  SET rs2 = conn2.Execute (strSQL)
  IF NOT rs2.EOF THEN
     call operation_to_do (using rs recordset)
  END IF
  rs.movenext
LOOP
```

This works fine, but is pretty slow (working over a few thousands records in each of the two servers). What I'd like to find is a more efficient and speedy way to do the same in this situation. Any ideia or suggestion ??
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Insert the `IdCode` into a new (temporary in memory) table on the second server, and use a join to select the data from the second server all at once.

Comment: Sorry but I did not understand. Should I make an insert into a new table for each IdCode from first recordset ? This way it will last even more I guess ...

Comment: I was wondering if it is possible to make SEARCH operations on a selected recordset. If yes, I could create a second recordset from second server, using just the "third condition" and then search, within this recordset in memory, if I find each IdCode from the first recordset !? But I have no idea about how to do this in ASP / ADO ...

Comment: Use `FEDERATED` engine.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to use the * in your first SELECT. You do not need all the fields there. Instead use only IdCode.